# Build SOA composties with Ant

Tags: ant, soa

I already have a build automation setup in Ant for SOA projects. It recompiles all the code even if there is no change in the code. Can anyone please suggest me the way out where I can only compile the changed SOA composites?

Answer (score 0):

Use Uptodate ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html

```
<target name="anythingChanged">
    <uptodate property="xmlBuild.notRequired" targetfile="${deploy}\xmlClasses.jar">
        <srcfiles dir= "${src}/xml" includes="**/*.dtd"/>
    </uptodate>
</target>

<target name="xmlBuild" depends="anythingChanged" unless="xmlBuild.notRequired">
  ...
</target>
```